# Does matrix element inequality implies norm inequality?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

Let $A$, $B$ be two $m{\times}n$ matrices and $u > 0$.  Suppose the corresponding elements from A and B satisfy
\begin{equation}
|B_{i,j}| \leq u | A_{i,j}|
\end{equation}
Can we prove 
\begin{equation}
||B||_1 \leq u ||A||_1
\end{equation}
where $||\cdot||_1$ is the matrix norm induced by $L_1$ vector norm? 
In general, can we prove the following?
\begin{equation}
||B||_p \leq u ||A||_p
\end{equation}

Comment: is $u$ a constant here?  It's more usual to use $C$ in that case ($u$ is traditionally a function)

Comment: Yes, u is a positive constant

Comment: This follows from the definitions and you should try to do the exercise.

Comment: I did try to prove it but it doesn't seem to follow the definitions directly.  $\exists x, ||x||_1=1$ such that $||B||_1 = ||Bx||_1 = \sum_i |\sum_j B_{ij} x_j| \leq \sum_{i,j} |B_{ij}| |x_j| \leq \sum_{i,j} u|A_{ij}||x_j| $.  But the last term is NOT  $\sum_{i,j} u|A_{ij}||x_j| \leq u||A||_1$